# Memory utilization in Taurus tool

Tags: python, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, blazemeter, taurus

In Taurus,I have come across and found that we can use taurus for real time reporting then jmeter,I can able to see the CPU,Memory utilization for the server were Server agent is running the services based on PID.How can i achieve the same using Taurus?As of now i can get cou,Memory based on whole server ,I need to get for particular Process id?

Below By using Taurus:

```
services:
 - module: monitoring
   server-agent:
  - address: 192.168.0.1:4444
    metrics:
    - cpu
    - disks
    - memory
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [PerfMon Documentation](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMonMetrics/#Specifying-Metric-Params) you should use something like:

```
cpu:pid=123456:percent
```

Replace `123456` with the actual PID you need to want to monitor.

Also be aware that there is a [Taurus Support Forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/codename-taurus) where you can reach out to Taurus developers and raise any issues or queries.

Just in case check out [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test) article to learn about PerfMon plugin usages as it is under the hood of the [Resource Monitoring](http://gettaurus.org/docs/Monitoring/) Taurus sybsystem

Comment: Is this fine:

services:
 - module: monitoring
   server-agent:
  - address: 192.168.0.1:4444
    metrics:
    - cpu
    - disks
    - memory
   cpu:pid=123456:percent

Comment: From taurus I am able to get CPU,If i use for memory giving the issue: "ValueError: could not convert string to float:". I used code as below: metrics:
    #- cpu
     - disks
     #- memory
     #- cpu:pid=8911:percent
     - mem:pid=8911:percent